# Настройка сервера на отображение контента

Tags: php, сервер

Есть код на PHP, который позволит отличить обычный запрос от AJAX запроса:

```
$is_ajax = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
    && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';

if ($is_ajax) {
    // Это AJAX запрос. Отдаем только часть страницы
    // ...
} else {
    // Это обычный запрос. Отдаем страницу целиком
    // ...
}
```

Вот код который генерирует контент:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.link', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
var link = $(this).attr('href');
if (link == 'index.html' {
      $('#content').prev('.slider').show();
} else {
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: link,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#spinner').show();
        },
        success: function(mes){
            $('#content').prev('.slider').hide();
            $('#content').html(mes);
            reinitOpacity();
            $(window).scroll();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#spinner').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

});

Подскажите как научить сервер отдавать либо всю страницу целиком (для обычных запросов), либо только блок, обновляемый через AJAX (без шапки, футера и т.п.)

Comment: А где же так часть кода, которая генерирует контент? :)

Comment: добавил код генерации контента

Comment: Контент у вас генерируется на серверной стороне. Так зачем же вы привели JavaScript код?

Comment: так нет у меня кода который генерирует контент на серверной стороне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не имею ни малейшего понятия что *именно* должна отображать страница о которой вы говорите, но попробую дать ответ на вопрос в самой общей постановке.

Для простоты, предположим, что у вас нет ни базы данных, ни шаблонизатора, ни какого-либо фреймфорка. Все что есть -- это одна страница с кодом:

```
function generate_content() {
    $characters = array(
        'Philip J. Fry',
        'Turanga Leela',
        'Bender Bending Rodríguez',
        'Hubert J. Farnsworth',
        'Hermes Conrad',
        'John A. Zoidberg',
        'Amy Wong',
    );

    // Перемешаем персонажей, что-бы создать иллюзию обновления данных
    shuffle($characters);

    $markup = '';
    foreach ($characters as $name) {
        $markup .= '<li>' . $name . '</li>';
    }

    return '<ul>' . $markup . '</ul>';
}

$is_ajax = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
    && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';

if ($is_ajax) {
    // Это AJAX запрос. Отдаем только часть страницы
    echo(generate_content());
} else {
    // Это обычный запрос. Отдаем страницу целиком
    echo('<html><head></head><body><div id="content">');
    echo(generate_content());
    echo('</div></body></html>');
}
```